# Convert Rewrite Rule Prefix Matching from Apache to Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

How to convert Apache's prefix matching to Nginx?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^/test1/(.*)$ http://newsite/test1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ http://newsite/foo/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/bar/(.*)$ http://newsite/bar/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is it something like this?

```
location / {
   rewrite ^/(test1|foo|bar)/(.*)$   http://newsite/$1/$2 permanent;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rewrite` is not bad.  It will work.  The only thing is that people prefer the `return` directive in `nginx` because it is a little faster (`nginx` needs to do less processing).

---

I'm not very familiar with `apache` rewrites so i might be slightly wrong in my interpretation of them but i believe that you only want to `rewrite` URLs under `/test1`, `/foo` and `/bar`.  For that purpose you do not even need the `rewrite` directive, you can make it with a simple `return` in `nginx`

```
location /test1 {
    return 301 http://newsite$request_uri;
}
location /foo {
    return 301 http://newsite$request_uri;
}
location /bar {
    return 301 http://newsite$request_uri;
}
location / {
    ...  # pages on this domain
}
```

Using a `regex` is a little slower:

```
location ~ /(test1|foo|bar) {
    return 301 http://newsite$request_uri;
}
```

And you can use a `rewrite` directive too, if you really want:

```
location ~ /(test1|foo|bar) {
    rewrite ^ http://newsite$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: @Kokizzu - Correct.  `location /test1` is a **prefix match** and will match `/test1/aaaa`.  Also, `$request_uri` will contain everything after the doiman (i.e. `/test/aaaa`).